# How to find a particular object in DevTools memory snapshot if the type of the object is just "Object"?

Tags: javascript, debugging, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

`queryObjects` function returns instances of a given prototype.
I want to inspect retainers of those instances. To do that I need to find them in devtools memory snapshot. One of those instances type is "Object", so searching by class type isn't helpful. They are just too many of them.

How can I find that particular instance in a snapshot?

Answer (score 5):

It would be very hard to distinct the plain "Objects" returned by `queryObjects` from all of the plain Objects in the heap snapshot

Here's what I've done to "tag" the objects so I can distinct them easily:

1. Create a `TaggedItem` class that can be easily found in dev tools
2. Create a wrapper function to be called in place of `queryObjects`
3. The wrapper functions saves return values inside a `WeakMap`

- the key is the original return value
- the value is a `TaggedItem`
- when the original value is no longer retained anywhere - it's automatically garbage collected from the `WeakMap`

Applying a decorator on `queryObjects`

```js
function queryObjects { /* Implementation */ }

// or process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'
if (__DEV__) {
  export default wrapWithObjectTagging(queryObjects);
}
else {
  export default queryObjects;
}
```

Decorator implementation

```js
function wrapWithObjectTagging(func) {
  function withObjectTagging(...args) {
     const originalReturnValue = func.apply(this, args);

     /* We're using Promise.resolve in case the original function returns a promise */
     Promise.resolve(originalReturnValue)
       .then((data) => {
         // Weak map keys can be objects only
         if (typeof data == 'object') {
           const tag = new TaggedItem(data);
           taggedItems.set(data, tag);
         }
     });

     return originalReturnValue;
  }

  return withObjectTagging;
}

/**
 * Capture tags in a weak map
 * When the original object (key) is no longer used anywhere in app - the data (TaggedItem)
 * is free for garbage collection and removed
 * Using dev tools we see which TaggedItems are still retained and what's using them - preventing GC
 * @type {WeakMap<object, TaggedItem>}
 */
const taggedItems = new WeakMap();

/**
 * Class instances are easily tracked by Dev tools memory snapshots
 * Wrapping a result with such instance allows us to track it without
 * incurring extra weight
 */
class TaggedItem {
  constructor(data) {
    // This ref helps us inspect what is retaining the original data
    this.ref = data;

    /* This is not really necessary but makes the TaggedItem represent 
       Retained Memory more accurately */
    Object.assign(this, data);    
  }
}
```

The `TaggedItem` is referencing the original data directly, but since nothing is referencing the `TaggedItem` - we never expose it - it does not prevent the `WeakMap` from garbage collecting the original data and the `TaggedItem` that captured it

---

Here is a sample of how that works in Chrome Dev Tools:

1. Take a Heap Snapshot
2. Search for the object class name (TaggedItem)
3. Select an item
4. See retainers

Example

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Memory Usage Snapshot]

- We're observing a `TaggedItem`
- It's retained by the `report` property of another object, that uses the original data

---

A simpler approach is to append a key to the original object

Decorating by appending a custom field

```js
function wrapWithObjectTagging(func) {
  function withObjectTagging(...args) {
     const originalReturnValue = func.apply(this, args);
     if (typeof originalReturnValue == 'object') {
       originalReturnValue.__tag = new TaggedItem();
     }

     return originalReturnValue;
  }

  return withObjectTagging;
}

class TaggedItem {}
```

This way you can still filter by `TaggedItem` in dev tools and see what's retaining the `TaggedItem` and in turn the parent object

The first approach gives a better estimate of total retained memory, while the simple approach would just allow you to trace what's retaining the original

Comment: What goes in function `queryObjects { /* Implementation */ } ` ? How to call this? Or is this our code that returns an object?

Comment: `queryObjects` is actually a utility func available in Chrome dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities#queryObjects-function. I misinterpreted it for a user-made object factory. The OP said that they want to use memory snapshot and identify retainers, so the solution here is still applicable - we wrap or apply a `TaggedItem` to objects in our app - then we can search for `TaggedItem` in a memory snapshot or via `queryObjects`  on the dev console

Comment: thanks, one thing i found is need to restart nodejs for global object changes like creating a new class type. noob issues

Answer (score 3):

Add explicit string property e.g. `let o = {type:'myType'}` and then use `ctrl`+`F` in snapshot.

[image]

There retainers are all your `o` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to modify these objects you can try the following trick.

Store the array you got from the queryObjects into a temp variable. You can do it via the context menu. Then run the following code to give each object a unique id:

```js
temp1.forEach((t, i) => t.__id = String(i))
```

Then take a heap snapshot. Now each object should be identifiable by that __id string.

Comment: The issue is that I want to find the one with type "Object". To do that I would need to go through the list of objects grouped as "Object" but even if I only look at the latest objects there are still to many of them to check them one by one.

Comment: If you know which object you're looking for on JS side, you can put a large string into it. Then once you sort the heap snapshot by retaining size, the object should pop up to the top.